# Converting a line plot to a scatter in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am making a line plot of the array `A`. Is there a way to convert it to a scatter plot? I present the current output for reference.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


A=np.array([[0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.0201082 ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02055473],
       [0.02055797],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ]])


plt.title("Line graph")
plt.plot(A, color="red")
```

The current output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scatter plot requires 2 variables, you only have one here.

I believe you rather want a line plot without line and with the individual points:

```
plt.plot(A, color="red", ls='', marker='o')
```

Output:

[image]